# Accordion that can have all sections closed on mobile, but always has one accordion section open on tablets and desktop

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have an accordion that only has one section open at a time. On desktop/tablet screen sizes, there would need to always be a section that is open so there isn't a blank area. But on mobile, this same accordion will need the ability to have all sections closed (i.e. if you click on an already open section it will close and no other section will open).

Here is a jsfiddle of what I have so far. It seems that the nested if else statement isn't being fired, and is only using the else from the un-nested if else statement. https://jsfiddle.net/bluebomber/x40jq16L/1/

This is the jQuery I am currently using:

```
$('li').click(function(width) {
   var thisClicked = $(this);
   if (width <= 767) {
      if (thisClicked.hasClass('selected')) {
         $('li').removeClass('selected');
      } else {
         $('li').removeClass('selected');
         thisClicked.addClass('selected');
      }
   } else {
      $('li').removeClass('selected');
      thisClicked.addClass('selected');
   }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You use `width`, but with is a information object about the event click.

If you use `console.log(width);` you can see the object.
Try with this:

```
$('.tabs.standard > ul > li').click(function(event) {
   console.log(event); // event(before called width) is a object, no integer or numeric value...
   var thisClicked = $(this),
   width = $(this).outerWidth(); // This calculate width
   if (width <= 767) {
      if (thisClicked.hasClass('selected')) {
         $('.tabs.standard > ul > li').removeClass('selected');
      } else {
         $('.tabs.standard > ul > li').removeClass('selected');
         thisClicked.addClass('selected');
      }
   } else {
      $('.tabs.standard > ul > li').removeClass('selected');
      thisClicked.addClass('selected');
   }
});
```

Learn about `outerWidth` here:
http://api.jquery.com/outerwidth/

Comment: This seems to add the functionality that I need for the ability of all accordions to be closed on mobile, but this is carrying over to desktop too. I need at least one of the accordions to be open at all times on mobile so there isn't a blank space.